# How to combine strings from 2 files into 1 and separate by space?

Tags: linux, file, text, sed, grep

I  have a problem with combine string from two other files into one, in OS linux.

For example:
I have file1.txt and file2.txt
file1.txt contain strings

```
word1
word2
word3
word4
```

file2 contain strings

```
a
b
c
d
```

How create new file with contains?

```
word1 a
word2 b
word3 c
word4 d
```

Comment: `paste file1.txt  file2.txt >new.txt`?

Comment: Yes, but how do if file1 contain 1 string?

Comment: I suggest you try it.

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let your  `file1.txt` contains

```
word1
word2
word3
word4
```

and `file2.txt` contains

```
a
b
c
d
```

Then to create a new file `file3.txt` with a space between two columns, use the following command in terminal.

```
paste -d' ' file1.txt file2.txt > file3.txt
```

Here the `-d` keyword is used to put a delimiter(here it is a space) between two columns. 
And you will get below result in `file3.txt`

```
word1 a
word2 b
word3 c
word4 d
```

Hope it is clear.